# VI delete everything except a pattern

Tags: regex, vim, pattern-matching, vi

I have a huge JSON output and I just need to delete everything except a small string in each line.

The string has the format

```
"title": "someServerName"
```

the "someServerName" (the section within quotes) can vary wildly.

The closest I've come is this:

```
:%s/\("title":\s"*"\)
```

But this just manages to delete

```
"title": "
```

The only thing I want left in each line is

```
"title": "someServerName"
```

EDIT to answer the posted question:

The Text I'm going to be working with will have a format similar to

```
{"_links": {"self": {"href": "/api/v2/servers/32", "title": "someServerName"},tons_of_other_json_crap_goes_here
```

All I want left at the end is:

```
"title": "someServerName"
```

Comment: Can you post what your input is and what your expected output is ? It is quite unclear in your post

Answer (score 14):

It should be `.*` rather than `*` to match a group of any characters.  This does the job:

```
%s/^.*\("title":\s".*"\).*$/\1/
```

Explanation of each part:

- `%s/` Substitute on each matching line.
- `^.*` Ignore any characters starting from beginning of line.
- `\("title":\s".*"\)` Capture the title and server name.  `".*"` will match any characters between quotes.
- `.*$` Ignore the rest of the line.
- `/\1/` The result of the substitution will be the first captured group.  The group was captured by parentheses `\(...\)`.

Comment: Could you please provide a breakdown of what each of those parts mean? I think I know a lot of them, but often times people explain them differently. I also want to see if I can try to change this to leave every instance of "title": "someServerName" if there are multiple instances of that pattern in file

Comment: Ok, I added a breakdown.  The command does handle multiple matching lines.

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like a job for `grep`.

```
:%!grep -o '"title":\s*"[^"]*"'
```

For more help with Vim's filtering see `:h :range!`.

See `man grep` for more information on the `-o`/`--only-matching` flag.

Answer (score 1):

It's quit convenient if you break the replace command into two steps as below. (p.s. I learned this skill from good guide book 《Practical Vim》 recently).

**Step 1： Search the contents that you want to keep**

- `\v"title":\s.*"`
  This will match "title": "someServerName". You can try again and again with command `q/` to open the search command window and modify the regular expression (This is the most excellent part I think).
- `\v^.*("title":\s.*").*$`
  Then add bracket for latter use and add .* to match other parts that you wish to delete.

**Step 2: Replace the matched contents**

- `:%s//\1/g` Note the original string in this substitute command is the matched part in last search (Very good feature in vim). And `\1` means using the matched group which is actually the part you wish to keep.

Hope you can find it more convenient than the long obscure substitute command.

Answer (score -1):

```
 %s/\v.*("title":\s".*").*/\1
```

Explanation and source [here](https://www.superuser.com/questions/559531/in-vim-how-to-delete-all-words-and-characters-not-matching-a-pattern#559552).

Answer (score -1):

I think the most elegant way to solve this is using ':g'
More comprehensive details in this link below!
[Power fo G](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Power_of_g)

It may not fully archive what you're looking, but damn close ;)

Comment: Keep in mind that this is a very old post. and try to post a specific answer e.g. use :g!/pattern/d